# Terraform: unknown resource type: google_cloud_run_v2_service

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
Terraform v1.4.6
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.74.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.0
```

According to [this documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_v2_service), the terraform resource exists. However, when trying to use

```
terraform import google_cloud_run_v2_service.cloud-run project-id/us-east4/service-name
```

The error I get is `unknown resource type: google_cloud_run_v2_service`. What's going on here? Is the documentation lying or am I doing something wrong?

My .tf file as it currently is for the moment while I import.

```
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "cloud-run" {
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `google_cloud_run_v2_service` was added in [version 4.46.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4460-december-12-2022) of the Terraform Google provider. Your provider version according to the question is `3.74.0`. You will need to update the provider version accordingly:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.46.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I actually learned something new about terraform providers here.

Comment: terraform init -upgrade did the trick ultimately.